# What is a Swirling Pool?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am currently fishing in Valley of the Four Winds, in the 'Gilded Fan' part of the zone, and can see quite a few 'Swirling Pools' in the water as per the below image:

[image: Swirling Pool]

I have tried fishing in these pools but haven't caught anything yet, what are these pools for? Are they purely aesthetic or for a quest or have some other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wowhead.com](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30051) (and a couple of other WoW wikis) they are a part of the quest **The Great Water Hunt** given by Mudmug.

> Guide Mudmug to Swirling Pools within the Gilded Fan, and help him collect 30 pawfuls of Gladewater.
>   If you become separated from Mudmug, you can find him next to the giant banana in the Gilded Fan.

Comment: This would explain a lot, I skipped all the quests in Valley of the Four Winds!